# Ctrl+Alt+Shift shortcuts not working on Linux Mint 19

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, mate

I migrated from **Mint 17.3 MATE**  to **Mint 19 MATE** and my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> keyboard shortcuts stopped working.

If I try to enter a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> shortcut in `mate-keybinding-properties`, the Alt doesn't register

For example: If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, it registers as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

**This is an Xorg bug** and as I understand it manifests itself by Xorg giving preference to shorter shortcuts before more complex ones that include the same keys as a subset.

There is a patch in the [Freedesktop bugzilla ticket](https://bugzilla.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865#c200) and you can install it using the commands below (documented already in [this Cinnamon issue on Github](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/7664)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! But to see the changes I had to restart the system.

Comment: It didn't work for me in Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia. Even ALT+TAB fails intermittently. Moving window between monitors with SHIFT+SUPER+ARROW rarely works.

Comment: Which patch is to install? I will be glad not to upgrade all my system through `apt dist-upgrade` for only this feature...

Answer (score 3):

It is an old bug (check [the bugtracker here](https://bugzilla.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865)), and **there is a patch**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update

# install the patch from ppa
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

#### Explanation

As I understood, Linux Mint starting from the version 19 uses the updated version of the XOrg-system, which uses the `keypress` event instead of the old good `keyrelease`, and now the shortest shortcuts hide the longer ones. This behavior is encouraged by XOrg itself.

The installed patch changes the settings of the XOrg (*though, I'm not sure about the last statement*).

Comment: Mint *v19 Tara x86_64*, `add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` fails with `HTTP Error 404: Not Found`, then `Cannot add PPA: ''This PPA does not support bionic''.`.

Comment: You are right. I have checked in Ubuntu `16.04` vs `18.04`. On `16.04` layout is changing while I was releasing `Left shift` or `Alt`. I'm trying to find hot to change behavior for `18.04`

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "_alt_" /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg
```

to view all binding with <kbd>alt</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>  You can even modify it at your preference.

Comment: Thanks. It's only getting me `  altwin:ctrl_alt_win = +altwin(ctrl_alt_win)
  altwin:swap_alt_win = +altwin(swap_alt_win)
  grp:ctrl_alt_toggle = +group(ctrl_alt_toggle)
  grp:ctrl_alt_toggle_bidir = +group(ctrl_alt_toggle_bidir)
  terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp = +terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)
`. No conflict with the keybindings I'm trying to setup (/carry over from my old system).

Comment: It looks like I might be affected by this bug https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-control-center/issues/132

Answer (score 0):

I started over from scratch (no problem there) and migrated only some of my select settings and everything worked all right.

Then the problem resurfaced when I added a different keyboard layout and set `Alt+Shift` as the key combo to switch layouts.

It looks like in Mint 19, unlike in Mint 17.3 (I imagine the underlying Ubuntus will probably be affected too), there's some kind of a conflict between the two settings.

I "solved" the problem by setting `Both Alts` as my layout switching combo, but I would call the conflict a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The problem only occurs when several keyboard layouts are installed (see https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/766). I have removed my second layout and the shortkeys now run.

However: no shortkey was defined for the switch between the layouts, so I can't understand, why a problem occurred.